# what php strategy to use to support frontend ajax calls?

Tags: php, ajax

I want to refactor my php site which supports a front end which makes ajax calls. 
Currently my ajax calls a php page which stores all my backend code and based on the parameters passed from the ajaxcall it determines which php methods to run.

I realize building a rest API as the php backend woudl be better but was wondering if there is another alternative? ie a good way to structure a php page that allows for clean re-usable ajax calls from the front end?

Thanks

Comment: try a framework like laravel

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of doing such kind of web development. It could be REST based micro framework approach in PHP where you invoke different views. Another could be to invoke the PHP code solely based on the input or interactions on the view (HTML/Javascript) using AJAX. Depends what you want to achieve.